# Export jar with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I need to export executable jar from intellij spring boot project. its basic rest only. How can it possible. I have created the artifact jar and when i try to run it with java -jar xxx.jar it returns manifest file not found error.

Comment: Which tool are you using to export your jar? IDE? Maven? Gradle?

Comment: There's a Maven plug in that will create the fat executable JAR with dependencies for you.

Comment: maven..........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you have this error when you generate the JAR using the IDE directly (export option of Eclipse for example).

You can either use the Maven goals `clean install` or `clean package` to compile and generate the JAR in your `target` folder and/or local repository.

> **package** - take the compiled code and package it in its distributable
>   format, such as a JAR.
>
> **install** - install the package into the local repository, for use as a
>   dependency in other projects locally

The `install` will execute the `package` one step before install it on your local repository.

[Maven Lifecycle Documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed maven, On the terminal of Intellij Idea use following code. 

`mvn clean package`

Your Jar will be saved inside "target" folder inside the project directory